# How can I prevent the app from showing "interesting" questions from sites I don't care about?

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, ios-app-feed

The app Feed display shows questions that something considers "interesting" from around the network. However, some of the questions it suggests are from sites that I'm not interested in (or I can't even read the language).

Is there a way to omit certain sites from those used for "interesting" or "hot"? (What's the difference between those, anyway?)

Comment: Ideally it would just correspond to what's shown by `.../id/username?tab=activity`.

Comment: Same problem. I sometimes discover interesting question but sometimes I feel tempted to answer and that usually ends up in low quality answers (or deleted comments). So I would prefer to limit the selection and at least remove the most annoying communities.