# Feed flooded with unwanted info

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, ios-app, ios-app-feed

I spend most of my time on Stack Overflow, and I just joined the Mathematics Stack Exchange site a few days ago. Ever since then the feed on my iOS app has been flooded with unwanted posts, hot questions/topics, and other things with tags that I have never even answered or asked questions for. Is this intentional, and is it because I joined another Stack Exchange network site?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is intentional, and yes, it's most likely because you joined the site. 
The feed is designed to show questions from **across the network**, and joining a site gives it a hint that you may be interested in questions from it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but why am I getting things on my feed with tags that I've never viewed or from sites I have not joined?

Comment: The idea is to have users learn about and participate in other sites across the network. So oftentimes the feed tries to show  content you may find interesting, even for sites you haven't joined.

Comment: Is there a way to disable this? I find it very annoying and useless because I was used to a feed with just info pertaining to what I had answered, asked, or commented on. Now there's way too much clutter and I can't find what I need easily.

Comment: Sorry, there isn't, although we've had some some feature requests to hide certain sites. You could try viewing questions for a single site by going directly to it on the app.

Comment: Ok, do you think those requests will be considered? My feed literally has things from sites I've never visited, and topics I've never searched for.

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: There is a question asking for a [similar feature] (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220387/how-can-i-prevent-the-app-from-showing-interesting-questions-from-sites-i-don) that's been around for a long time. Making these types of changes requires significant API changes, which isn't easy (and requires help from other team members). However, keep your feedback in mind.