# Please don't show updates from sites in another language in the app feed

Tags: bug, android-app, hot-questions, languages, android-app-feed

Related to [How can I prevent the app from showing "interesting" questions from sites I don't care about?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/220387/205264)

Now that Stack Overflow is being rolled out in other languages, would it be possible that these sites don't show up in the app feed, or -preferably- that this is made an opt-in feature, or -at least- opt-out?

These languages are only useful to a small subset of all app users.

It at least happens with the 'hot' questions:

[image: hot question from pt.so]

(Note: the Careers Overflow item in Dutch is OK, since it's location-based, if I'm not mistaken, and I'm in the Netherlands. I'm talking about the Portugese item)

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of this happening? I'd like to see under which category this is popping up.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi sure, done!

Comment: Aha, it's under hot questions. We'll get this fixed up, thanks!

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi great, thanks! I updated the question to a [tag:bug] instead of a [tag:feature-request].