# Let me filter the iOS app Hot Questions

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, hot-questions, ios-app-feed

*note: this should not be duplicate of [Filtering "hot" questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/84389/191980) since its about ios-app*

I use iOS app mostly to read Hot Questions (95% of the time), while riding a public transport or before bed. (I rarely almost never, read hot questions on computer; in fact I discovered hot questions when I installed iOS app itself a year ago)

I use iOS app every day (important), and it is a nightmare to read same question title twice or trice.

It would be convenient to filter hot questions by

1. new - questions that I have not read yet
2. participated in - questions that I have interacted with (upvote, comment...)
3. old - questions that I have seen && not interacted with

---

*below part already requested as mentioned by Shadow Wizard - [How can I prevent the app from showing "interesting" questions from sites I don't care about?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/220387/191980)*

Global filter to remove certain stackexchange sites from "my hot questions"; or just add functionality to swipe to hide (in that case just filter for hidden, all, not-hidden).

Comment: The last part (remove sites) is already requested: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220387/how-can-i-prevent-the-app-from-showing-interesting-questions-from-sites-i-don

Comment: @ShadowWizard question edited; thank you.

Comment: related: [Increase the Hot Network Questions randomness (proposal for testing)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247195/165773). "Some questions appear to stick in the hot list for quite a long. As a result, site visitors complain about being repeatedly fed from sidebar with useless links to already visited questions..."

Comment: I would change "old" to "read"